# (SyntaxError) web/controllers/registration_controller.ex:16: syntax error before: '->' - Elixir

Tags: error-handling, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm brand spanking new to Phoenix and Elixir. So far, it's awesome, but there is a learning curve to be had. Right now, I'm getting this error while following a tut and I can't seem to see what is wrong. `(SyntaxError) web/controllers/registration_controller.ex:16: syntax error before: '->'`

Registration_controller:

```
defmodule Restore.RegistrationController do
  use Restore.Web, :controller
  alias Restore.User

  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{})
    render conn, changeset: changeset
  end

  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)

    case Restore.Registration.create(changeset, Restore.Repo) do
      {:ok, changeset} ->
        # sign in the user
      {:error, changeset} ->
        # show error message
    end
  end
end
```

Error:

```
    Compiling 2 files (.ex)

== Compilation error on file web/controllers/registration_controller.ex ==
** (SyntaxError) web/controllers/registration_controller.ex:16: syntax error before: '->'
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:116: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

Sorry if this is a bad question, but for the life of me I can't seem to get it right. Any help would be great thank you!

Comment: is `# sign in the user` some code that's been redacted or just a comment? Because if it's just a comment, the compiler expects a statement that's not there, which will fail. The error should point to `{:error, changeset}` in that case, since that's the thing it sees instead of the statement it expects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to complete your registration process (add code instead of the comment), there's nothing you're doing with each case, this is an example from an app that uses JWT authentication:

```
  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        {:ok, jwt, _full_claims} = Guardian.encode_and_sign(user, :token)

        conn
        |> put_status(:created)
        |> render(Restore.SessionView, "show.json", jwt: jwt, user: user)

      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render(Restore.RegistrationView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
    end
```